# =excel 2013 if function not working as it should be

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example i have 4 cells:A1, A2, A3, A4 :
A1=50
A2=10
A3=if(A1>A2,"-1","0")
A4= if(A3=-1,"ok,"not ok")
but the problem is that A4 keeps giving "not ok" ! whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change A3 to `=if(A1>A2,-1,0)`; take out the quotes.

Comment: I also assume A4= if(A3=-1,"ok,"not ok")  is a typo & should be =IF(A3=-1,"ok","not ok")